# How to change <li> or <tr> color after one another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i want to change the color of li or tr whatever possible after one another.

Note:- I want to call this in while loop so static class will be no solution

I want the output lke:-

```
<li>line1</li> //white background
<li>line2</li> //red background
<li>line3</li> //white background
<li>line4</li> //red background
```

or if possible in  like:-

```
<tr>
<td>line1</td>  //white background
</tr>
<tr>
<td>line2</td>  //red background
</tr>
<tr>
<td>line3</td>  //white background
</tr>
<tr>
<td>line4</td>  //red background
</tr>
```

What i am trying yet is:-

```
<?php
$fields = CFS()->get('gallery');
foreach ($fields as $field) { <?
<table>
<tr><td><?php echo $field['slide_title']; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td><?php echo $field['upload']; ?></td></tr>
</table>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: What language are you using to create this html? (you said you where doing it a while loop?)

Answer (score 10):

You could achieve this by CSS `:nth-of-type` odd and even selector.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/y0xbbLcu/)**

```
li:nth-of-type(odd) {
    color:red;
}
li:nth-of-type(even) {
    color:blue;
}
```

And for `td`s selector:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rrkeqajg/)**

```
table tr:nth-of-type(odd) {
    color:red;
}
table tr:nth-of-type(even) {
    color:blue;
}
```

You could also use CSS `:nth-child` selector like this:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rrkeqajg/2/)**

```
table tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
    color:red;
}
table tr:nth-child(2n) {
    color:blue;
}
```

**NOTE:** `tr:nth-child(2n)` - Represents the even rows of an HTML table.

**and** `tr:nth-child(2n+1)` - Represents the odd rows of an HTML table.

> - [Mozilla MDN :nth-of-type selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)
> - [Mozilla MDN :nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This is What i am looking for will you plz let me know one thing more that how can i partition in li tag using span?

Comment: +1 for sane solution. CSS is definitely the way to go here. I'd prefer `:nth-child` myself, but both work.

Comment: Kudos For this Solution Buddy. all solutions in one. great. @Mary Melody

Comment: +1 for suggesting `:nth-of-type`. In a *valid* markup the effect of `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` would be the same in this particular instance. However `:nth-of-type` will work even if the list element or the table contains other types of elements - in addition of list items or table rows -  mistakenly.

Answer (score 0):

try this php code,

```
$i = 1;
$result = "";
while(ur-condition)
{
  if($i%2 == 0)
    $result .= "<li style='background-color: red'>line$i</li>";
  else
   $result .= "<li style='background-color: white'>line$i</li>";
  $i++;
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
*{margin:0; padding:0; font-family:Arial; font-size:12px; color:#333;}
ul, li{list-style:none;}
ul{margin:10px;}
li:nth-child(odd){background-color:blue;}
li:nth-child(even){background-color:red;}
li{line-height:22px; padding:5px; color:#fff;}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Karthik_Dev/upesszbs/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery which will also work in older version of ie

http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/96d0k2zo/

```
$( "tr:odd , ul li:odd" ).css( "background-color", "#bbbbff" );
```